# ArcGIS Pro Forest-based Classification and Regression fails with error

Tags: arcgis-pro, error, random-forest

I'm trying to run a Random Forest Classification and Regression in ArcGIS Pro 2.3.2. I've already run this analysis using Bayesian logistic regression in R, and want to compare the results from RF.

I have options set to Prediction Type = Raster, am using a polygon layer as the Training Features, selected the Variable to Predict and checked Categorical (it's a 0/1 presence/absence variable), input Training Rasters and checked the ones that are categorical, and specified an Output Prediction Surface (see image below).

[image]

The process makes it past "Reading Data" and "Getting Centroids", but then immediately fails with the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File `"<string>"`, line 10175, in execute
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSForest.py", line 6638,
>   in execute created = rasterWorkFlow(*infoRasterArg)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSForest.py", line 6441,
>   in rasterWorkFlow checkBalance = not hpar.balanceTree)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSForest.py", line 216,
>   in loadDataRasterForTraining
>   self.createVariablesFromRasterList(infoRaster, dataX)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSForest.py", line 284,
>   in createVariablesFromRasterList errors, info =
>   self.variableTest(name, dataBlock, userType, id)
>
> File "C:\Program
>   Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\SSForest.py", line 318,
>   in variableTest info = field.info
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'info'
>
> Failed to execute (Forest).

Obviously, the SSForest.py script is failing at specific lines, but I don't know what the issue is. All the lines in the error  message seem to relate to the `loadDataRasterForTraining` (line 203) and `loadDataRasterForPredicting`(line 252) functions in [the script](http://pythonfiddle.com/forest_based-classification-and-regression). Any ideas what might be causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out the problem after digging through the code for SSForest.py and trying different combinations of input data in the geoprocessing menu.

The Variable to Predict from your Training Features **must** be a text string. Using a field with categorical numeric codes causes the tool to fail, even after checking Treat Variable as Categorical.